# Can't access User Secrets in ASP.net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

My question is simple.
I have an ASP.net core 3.0 app, I added secrets using visualstudio and pasted my secrets into the secret file normally. 
Then inside my Program.cs, I added a call to addusersecrets as follows:

```
...
...
.AddUserSecrets<Startup>()
```

But while calling my secrets like `Configuration["Authentication:Secret"]` as I used to do when it was in appsettings.json, I get a null value in return.

I went through stackoverflow and tried solutions like changing my addsecrets as follows:

```
.AddUserSecrets("fds...-...-...askd")

//OR

.AddUserSecrets(typeof(Startup).Assembly, true, reloadOnChange: true)
```

BUt none of then works.

I wonder if this secret stuff even works on asp.net core, because I don't see any reason my code doesn't work. please if someone gets it, can you tell me a solution ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did your code look like this ?

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", 
                     optional: false, 
                     reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
    }

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: yeah it did. it is similar to that.

Comment: can you show me how you read your config file in your c# code

Comment: Hi, I do the build in my Program.cs instead it looks like this:    ```var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddUserSecrets<Startup>(true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
```

Comment: Thanks, you made me realise I was running my configs in a different way, adding my configs in the startup.cs and calling the user secrets there helped me.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure to check that you've set the `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"` variable to `"Development"`, else your app wont add your user secrets.

- in powershell:

  > $Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
- cmd:

  > setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Development"

Comment: What will be the approach say for e.g a app in the production  environment?

Comment: @David -- I know your question is old, but you do not use "user secrets"/secrets.json in a production environment. It is strictly for local development. You'd want to use Azure Key Vault or Azure App Configuration for storing production secrets, keys, connection strings, etc.

Answer (score 2):

For .Net 6 that doesn't use `Startup` one loads the assembly such as

```
build.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
```

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net MVC 5, add this to Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configuration) =>
                {
                    configuration.Sources.Clear();
                    configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                    configuration.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true, true);
                    
                })
                .UseSystemd()
                .UseSerilog((context, service, configuration) => {
                    configuration
                    .MinimumLevel.Warning()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.Console();

                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
 
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
                
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

User secrets are stored now in csproj project file. This is how you can read it(see image). I am using asp.net core 5
[image: instructions]

Comment: I need to access the user-secrets for a project that does not contain a Startup.cs.